# Pandas data types change when iterating over the major axis

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I create a simple DataFrame like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import heapq

a = [1371215933513120, 1371215933513121]
b = [1,2]
d = ['h','h']
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':a, 'b':b, 'c':[dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(t/1000000.) for t in a], 'd':d})
df.index=pd.DatetimeIndex(df['c'])

d = OrderedDict()
d['x'] = df
p = pd.Panel(d)
p['x']['b'] = p['x']['b'].astype(int)

counter = 0
for dt in p.major_axis:
    print "a", counter, p['x'].dtypes
    df_s = p.major_xs(dt)
    print "b", counter, p['x'].dtypes
    print "-------------"
    counter += 1
```

It consists of three columns, one of which is made the index. If start iterating over the major axis values, the data type of the `int` column changes to `object` after the first iteration.

```
a 0 a    object
b     int64
c    object
d    object
dtype: object
b 0 a    object
b    object
c    object
d    object
dtype: object
-------------
a 1 a    object
b    object
c    object
d    object
dtype: object
b 1 a    object
b    object
c    object
d    object
dtype: object
-------------
```

Is there a way of avoiding this so that columns retain their type while iterating?

Comment: dtype preservation is not guaranteed - try a multi level frame as your repr to have more control.

Comment: May I ask why? It seems kind of strange to change the underlying dtype when simply iterating over the entries, doesn't it?

Comment: you are not simply iterating; you are slicing (that's what major_xs) does. data are stored in 3-d dtype blocks; you are slicing across blocks.

Comment: Ahh, I see. But then why can't data types be guaranteed? It seems to me like if I have a chunk of objects, all of which are type x, then any subset of them must also contain only type x.

Comment: you are essentially doing a transposition type of operation (e.g. slicing on axis 1, yield a dataframe from axis 0 and 2). dtypes are column based, so this mixes things up. if you really want to do this, try ``convert_objects()`` on the resulting frame, it will clean this up.

Comment: I really appreciate your answers and forgive me if I'm being daft, but I still don't understand why slicing would change the types of the original object (`p['x']`). Shouldn't it just be the result (`df_s`) that is affected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your construction does not preserve the dtypes; if you construct this way, you will preserve them in the first place.

```
In [18]: df.set_index(['x','b']).to_panel()
Out[18]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 3 (items) x 1 (major_axis) x 2 (minor_axis)
Items axis: a to d
Major_axis axis: x to x
Minor_axis axis: 1 to 2

In [19]: p1 = df.set_index(['x','b']).to_panel()
```

This is the internal structure; dtypes are separated into blocks.

```
In [20]: p1._data
Out[20]: 
BlockManager
Items: Index([u'a', u'c', u'd'], dtype=object)
Axis 1: Index([u'x'], dtype=object)
Axis 2: Int64Index([1, 2], dtype=int64)
DatetimeBlock: [c], 1 x 1 x 2, dtype datetime64[ns]
ObjectBlock: [d], 1 x 1 x 2, dtype object
IntBlock: [a], 1 x 1 x 2, dtype int64
```

Using `iloc` on various axes you can see that dtypes are preserved

```
In [21]: p1.iloc[0].dtypes
Out[21]: 
b
1    int64
2    int64
dtype: object

In [22]: p1.iloc[:,0].dtypes
Out[22]: 
a             int64
c    datetime64[ns]
d            object
dtype: object

In [23]: p1.iloc[:,:,0].dtypes
Out[23]: 
a             int64
c    datetime64[ns]
d            object
dtype: object

In [24]: p1.iloc[:,:,0]
Out[24]: 
                  a                          c  d
x                                                
x  1371215933513120 2013-06-14 09:18:53.513120  h
```