# Why does Pandas Panel have messed up axes order?

Tags: python, pandas

The axes order seems really messed up to me in a Pandas Panel. Why is it this way?

Here's what I mean:

```
In [120]: import pandas as pd

In [121]: import numpy as np

In [122]: pnl = pd.Panel(np.random.randn(33, 55, 77))

In [123]: pnl.shape
Out[123]: (33, 55, 77)

In [124]: pnl[0].shape
Out[124]: (55, 77)

In [125]: pnl[0][0].shape
Out[125]: (55,)
```

So it starts out with shape (33, 55, 77) for axes 0, 1, 2, respectively. Great. If I take off an index with `pnl[0]`, it takes off the *first* axis (lengths 33) and leaves with with shape (55, 77). Still great. But then when I take off another index with `pnl[0][0]`, it doesn't take off the first two axes (lengths 33, 55) and leave me with shape (77,) as I would reasonably expect. Nope. It decides that, this time, it's going to take off the *last* axis instead of the *first* axis and leaves me with shape (55,). Huh?!?! Why is this so messed up? Can someone please explain to me the design logic behind this.

PS. I would really love to use Panel, but right now I'm not using it because of this axes issue. It makes the code unnecessarily confusing sometimes.

**UPDATE:**

Mr. F gave an answer below that basically suggests using `pnl.ix[...]` consistently instead of using `pnl[...]`. So, I gave it a try. However, I'm still running into really weird/confusing behavior.

Here's an example, using the same `pnl` object that was defined above:

```
In [220]: pnl.shape
Out[220]: (33, 55, 77)

In [221]: pnl.ix[:, 0, 0].shape
Out[221]: (33,)

In [222]: pnl.ix[0, :, 0].shape
Out[222]: (55,)

In [223]: pnl.ix[0, 0, :].shape
Out[223]: (77,)

In [224]: pnl.ix[:, :, 0].shape
Out[224]: (55, 33)

In [225]: pnl.ix[:, 0, :].shape
Out[225]: (77, 33)

In [226]: pnl.ix[0, :, :].shape
Out[226]: (55, 77)
```

Everything looks great when I take off 2 axes and leave just 1 axis (commands 221-223 above). But when I take off 1 axis to leave 2 axes (commands 224-226 above), the resulting shapes are again nonsensical. It's very hard to understand and get used to how the resulting shapes seem to magically swap axes order, but only sometimes! (Specifically, command 226 has the result shape (55, 77) that matches my expectation. However, in command 224, I would expect the result shape (33, 55) not (55, 33); in command 225, I would expect the result shape (33, 77) not (77, 33).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out a mental model that works! The good news is I think I can use Panel now, because this mental model is actually pretty simple!

It also doesn't matter whether I'm using `pnl[...]` or `pnl.ix[...]`. This simple mental model explains the behavior correctly in all cases!

Here is the model: For 3 dimensions like Panel, just imagine the axes are (first, third, second). For 2 dimensions like DataFrame, just imagine the axes are (second, first). This ordering of axes applies both for the shape tuples and for the order of indexes when using multiple indexes.

Now I will demonstrate how all the commands I typed in my original question, which seemed to give nonsensical results, make perfect sense in the mental model (I will add comments at the end of each line):

```
In [122]: pnl = pd.Panel(np.random.randn(33, 55, 77))  # mental: (first@33, second@77, third@55)

In [123]: pnl.shape
Out[123]: (33, 55, 77)  # mental: (first@33, second@77, third@55)

In [124]: pnl[0].shape  # mental: pnl[first=0]
Out[124]: (55, 77)  # mental: (first@77, second@55) was previously second@77,third@55

In [125]: pnl[0][0].shape  # mental: pnl[first=0][second=0]
Out[125]: (55,)  # mental: (first@55,) was previously third@55

...

In [220]: pnl.shape
Out[220]: (33, 55, 77)  # mental: (first@33, second@77, third@55)

In [221]: pnl.ix[:, 0, 0].shape  # mental: pnl.ix[:, third=0, second=0]
Out[221]: (33,)  # mental: (first@33,) was previously first@33

In [222]: pnl.ix[0, :, 0].shape  # mental: pnl.ix[first=0, :, second=0]
Out[222]: (55,)  # mental: (first@55,) was previously third@55

In [223]: pnl.ix[0, 0, :].shape  # mental: pnl.ix[first=0, third=0, :]
Out[223]: (77,)  # mental: (first@77,) was previously second@77

In [224]: pnl.ix[:, :, 0].shape  # mental: pnl.ix[:, :, second=0]
Out[224]: (55, 33)  # mental: (first@33, second@55) was previously first@33,third@55

In [225]: pnl.ix[:, 0, :].shape  # mental: pnl.ix[:, third=0, :]
Out[225]: (77, 33)  # mental: (first@33, second@77) was previously first@33,second@77

In [226]: pnl.ix[0, :, :].shape  # mental: pnl.ix[first=0, :, :]
Out[226]: (55, 77)  # mental: (first@77, second@55) was previously second@77,third@55
```

In summary, it all makes sense now (in a twisted way). There's no difference between `pnl[...]` and `pnl.ix[...]`. Just need to commit this simple mental model to memory.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the item-getter syntax (getting dimensions with square brackets `[]`) isn't the sort of thing you want. What you want is to ensure you are *sub-indexing* into the data along the dimensions you specify.

For this, you can use `ix`:

```
 pnl.ix[0, 0].shape
 (77,)
```

You get some insight into this by looking at the `type` of each of the things you have tried:

```
In [71]: type(pnl.ix[0, 0])
Out[71]: pandas.core.series.Series

In [72]: type(pnl.ix[0])
Out[72]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

In [73]: type(pnl[0])
Out[73]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

In particular the final two are looking at the same sub-DataFrame, but consider the difference between:

```
(pnl[0])[0]
# Or, (pnl.ix[0])[0]
```

and

```
pnl.ix[0, 0] 
# Or, (pnl.ix[0]).ix[0]
```

In the first case, you're saying "Hey, go ahead and fully do the operation '`pnl[0]`' and return whatever that is, then *after that* go ahead and item-get the 0th element again".

Since `pnl[0]` is a DataFrame, then the extra `[0]` item-get operation will be the same as `df[0]` for any old DataFrame, which will try to extract that column if it exists. The column dimension will be the first dimension of the resulting DataFrame, which is why it is length 55 instead of having row-length 77.

The main point is that in Python, saying `foo[x]` just means "call the special `__getitem__` method of `foo` with `x` as the argument" and nothing more. If, as with  DataFrame, this has a special convention (e.g. to reference a *column*) that is different than what you might expect in mathematical notation (in which case it would reference an item along the *first* axis, regardless of the shape or structure), this is just an implementation detail.

For example, with pure NumPy arrays, the repeated item-getting does what you happen to expect:

```
In [90]: pnl.values[0][0].shape
Out[90]: (77,)
```

That doesn't make this the "right" way to do it or anything. It's just *a* way that happens to correspond to certain conventions of mathematical linear algebra. Since a DataFrame seeks to represent *relational* data models and not purely multi-dimensional arrays, there's no reason to expect that Pandas has to emulate NumPy in this behavior.

**Added for more than 2 dimensions**

With more than 2 dimensions, these slicing operations represent implicit transposition of the data when compared to how it was laid out in the original 3-D Panel. So Pandas has to do something to resolve the layout of the sub-selected data, and it seems that when doing this, Pandas just did not implement the slicing methods in such a way as to guarantee that the left-to-right order of the axes is preserved.

So when the data is laid out in blocks, it seems to determine the new major (index) axis independently of what it stores from the parent Panel data.

For example, I created a random data set with the same shape, and I see:

```
In [22]: pnl.ix[:, 0, :]._data
Out[22]: 
BlockManager
Items: Int64Index([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
            17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32],
           dtype='int64')
Axis 1: Int64Index([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
            17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
            34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,
            51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67,
            68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76],
           dtype='int64')
FloatBlock: slice(0, 33, 1), 33 x 77, dtype: float64
```

In particular notice the final line, which says that *it does know* that it is a 33 x 77 block. Yet when we look at the `DataFrame` representation of that block:

```
In [23]: pnl.ix[:, 0, :].shape
Out[23]: (77, 33)
```

So you're very right that this arbitrary and undocumented process by which Pandas re-determines the axes ordering is problematic. This example should rightly be filed as a bug, either because the axes orders are not preserved, or else because whatever conditions are used to determine which ordering will be produced are not documented. The Pandas team ought to provide one or the other.

Comment: I updated my question above after trying your answer. Unfortunately, using `.ix[...]` still seems to cause nonsensical axes-swapping behavior. Please see my update above for details.

Comment: You only mentioned the sensical example from command 226. But what about the nonsensical swapped axes in commands 224 and 225? In command 224, I would expect the result shape (33, 55) not (55, 33); in command 225, I would expect the result shape (33, 77) not (77, 33).

Comment: I see what you're saying now, sorry I was hasty before. It looks like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359248/pandas-data-types-change-when-iterating-over-the-major-axis) can help you. The answer is a bit complicated.

Comment: I added a bit showing the `_data` and `blocks` attributes in this case. This does seem worthy of filing as a bug at the Pandas GitHub page -- either to make the axes ordering preserved or else document exactly how it is that the axis changes are computed from the data.